# How to write a sampling algorithm from a custom distribution?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I'm generating random galaxies with line of sight velocities drawn from a **normal distribution**, and random positions also from a **2d Gaussian**. It is a little more physical to draw these positions from an **NFW profile** given by:

```
rho(r) = rho_0/(r/R_s*(1+r/R_s)^2
```

where `rho_0` and `R_s` are constant parameters.

How can I write an algorithm to sample from this distribution ?

Basically I'm trying to plop down a couple hundred galaxies that follow this density distribution.

I've been just using `numpy.random.normal` to sample from the **Gaussians**, but I'd like to sample from the **NFW** profile rather than the **Gaussians**. I'm sure some stats training would probably be a good place to start, but a point in the right direction would be helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: There is a parenthesis missing in your formula. Could you make sure you write it out correctly? I am assuming the squared term should be in the denominator... Also, would you mind telling us what **NFW** stands for?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function rho(r), which takes values from [0..1] and returns values from [0..1], then it's pretty easy:

```
def getRhoSample():
  #get uniform random number
  value = numpy.random.random()

  #sample my custom function
  return rho(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this just gives me the densities at random radii. I need to sample from the density distribution such that the random generated points follow the NFW profile given by rho(r).

Comment: I understand the idea of using the CDF to do this, but the problem is the NFW profile is not a standard probability density function that is normalizeable; therefore, the cdf does not go to 1 as r goes to infinity.